# Asynchronous Socket Read Issue

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am having a program which uses tcp socket Asynchronous call to receive the protocol header which is 8 bytes.  When processing the ReadCallBack() [async call back],it uses synchronous  read to get the payload messages then process it.

My question is Whether ReadCallback method is thread safe. I am using normal dictionary to process those payload. Does it affect that dict in any mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is effectively thread-safe if it is in isolation; the important question is: what *else* is going on? What *else* is accessing (read or write) the dictionary? If nothing, then you should be fine - the callback will be invoked (which depending on the specific API being used, and the data available in the buffer, could be **either** on the thread issuing `Read...`, *or* on a completion-port thread), and then presumably you'll do some work with the dictionary before doing something else (read/write/close).

If, however, other threads are accessing the dictionary, then the question is impossible to answer without specific code.